# Difference between math.random() and math.randomseed() in Lua

Tags: lua, random-seed

I am working on game using Corona SDK with Lua as Programming Language . While getting random number from table , I am confused to use which one of following ?

```
math.random()
math.randomseed()
```

Will any one elaborate the exact difference between them ? So I can  use the best one in my case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need the same sequence when you call `math.random()`, then you must set `math.randomseed(same number every time before calling)` before calling `math.random()`.

If you want a different sequence of random numbers, then pass `math.randomseed(os.time())` before calling `math.random()` because `os.time()` will return the time in number of seconds so it will be different every time.

Please refer to following link and check example there.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/math/randomseed.html

Comment: You shouldn't set math.randomseed to os.time each time you call math.random! The seeds will be close together and it will in effect be less random. Just call it on the beginning and let math.random do it's work.

Answer (score 11):

`math.random` gives you random numbers. You probably will call this many times in a program that needs random numbers.

`math.randomseed` determines where to start the sequence of random numbers given by `math.random`. You probably will call just *once* in a program that needs random numbers.

It seems to be a common misconception that you need to call `math.randomseed` before each time you call `math.random`. This is *wrong* and will defeat the randomness of `math.random`.

Comment: I'm so glad you mentioned that last part. Master didn't and I commented before checking yours lol.

Comment: I'd also add that calling `randomseed` with the same number will give you the same sequence of numbers returned by `random`, which is sometimes convenient in game testing.

Answer (score 8):

When you execute a program that uses `math.random`, without setting `math.randomseed`, it will usually yield the same set of random numbers. This is due to the fact that `math.randomseed` is responsible for setting the default `seed` (or  algorithm-generator) for the random numbers brought out by `math.random`.

This consistency obviously is not random. Allow me to give an example - First go to the [Lua Demo Website](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) and then insert this piece of code:

```
for i = 1,10 do
print(math.random())
end
```

Keep on consistently hitting the **run** button and see how the interpreter will yield the same numbers each time. However, to change the 'seed' by which the random numbers are being generated, we can just set the 'seed' to whatever the current time is (since current time never repeats)

This time go on the website and execute this code multiple times:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
for i = 1,10 do
print(math.random())
end
```

You shall now note how you will get different numbers each time.