# Can I use self.math.random on 2 Npcs?

Tags: random, lua

I have this script on 2 npcs but both choose the same random number (7) how do I make the Npcs choose their own number? I did try with self.math.random and it gave an error
so what would the solution be? will I have to create different variables for each npc related to the random function?

```
function Behavior:Awake()
    math.randomseed (os.time())
self.destino = math.random( 1, 7 )
```

In the engine I work with it says to put self. for independence...

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you call `math.randomseed` inside a function suggests to me that you're calling it every time you want a random number. The purpose of `math.randomseed` is to *initialize* the RNG, which means you're initializing the RNG multiple times, hence the repetition. Usually, you need to call `math.randomseed` exactly once in the entire program.

> it says to put self. for independence...

That's not a great explanation of how `self` works. `self` is a function parameter that gets automatically declared when you declare a function with colon notation.

Comment: thank you so much! the solution was to put the "math.randomseed" before the Behavior Awake

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35455929/107090

Comment: @AloanMoreira if this answer resolved your issue then accept it, please - that's how you "thank" the user that helped you and that's how SO works