# How to write file for save a random number by Lua languages

Tags: function, random, lua

This is my function

```
function randomNum2(num)
    f = io.open("result.csv", "a+")
    num = math.randomseed(os.clock()*100000000000)
    f:write(string.format("%s\n", num))
    f:close()
    return "TETB"..(math.random(1000000000))
end
```

The output from `result.csv` file like.

```
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

I would like to know how to save a random number to `result.csv` file like this.

```
TETB539286665
TETB633918991  
TETB892163703  
TETB963005226  
TETB359644877  
TETB131482377
```

Any ideas on what the problem is and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, call `math.randomseed` *once* at the start of the program. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455489/difference-between-math-random-and-math-randomseed-in-lua/35455929#35455929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `math.randomseed` function doesn't return anything, it just sets the `math` library to use a certain number as the basis for the "random" numbers, you should use the `math.random` function after running `math.randomseed` which configures the library, `math.random` returns a number and you can specify a range between them, if you don't it will likely return a floating point number.

Also the `num` parameter is not being used and can be removed or renamed to `max` and used as an argument in the `math.random` call to serve as the maximum result number.

Answer (score 0):

Do more `local` variable.
And do not concat (..) a `string` with a `number`.
Convert `math.random()` with `tostring()`  on the fly.
I corrected your version to...

```
randomNum2=function()
    local f = io.open("result.csv", "a+")
    local rand = "TETB"..tostring(math.random(100000000000))
    f:write(string.format("%s\n", rand))
    f:close()
    return rand
end
```

...and `math.randomseed()` is not necessary.

Then you get a result.csv with what you want.
Tested in an interactive standalone Lua interpreter...

```
> for i=1,10 do randomNum2() end
> os.execute('cat result.csv')
TETB73252732829
TETB48306115776
TETB83524202926
TETB53376530639
TETB39893346222
TETB60394413785
TETB97611122173
TETB35725172461
TETB48950449408
TETB15779990338
true    exit    0
-- Next example puts out the return of the function.
-- That can be used without reading the file.
-- To check what was written/append to result.csv on the fly.
> print(randomNum2())
TETB73113866427
```